# Vibrating when reaching stored location in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, geolocation, app-inventor, vibration

I'm trying to modify MIT app inventor [tutorial](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/android-wheres-my-car.html) "Android, Where is my car?", by adding a vibrating function.

The phone should vibrate when the stored location data readings of "Lat" and "Long" is near the values of recent location data.

These are the blocks I'm using, but I get no function from vibrate sound, but only the notification alert.

[image]

What I'm I doing wrong? Is there another approach maybe? 
Please help me out on this mod, by pointing me to an example or a tutorial.
Thank you all for your answers.

[EDIT 1]

Thanks to @Taifun's recommendation link to the App Inventor forum, I found a way to make the vibration on location reached. 
Here is the used code blocks (thanks **aumandg** and [MIT App Inventor Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/fence/mitappinventortest/orsJ_Yosyxw/xF4p95vsCgAJ)):

[image]

If someone can point out a way to have the same functionality, using my original blocks with lat and long values, please respond. Other way, I'll keep this solution for now, till I get more experienced with App Inventor2.

Comment: Do a [search in the App Inventor forum for fence](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/fence) to find similar questions and answers

Comment: Hi @Taifun. Thank you for the commented link at App Inventor forum. I searched and found a thread (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/fence/mitappinventortest/orsJ_Yosyxw/xF4p95vsCgAJ) that did the trick.

Comment: you might want to add your solution as answer below and ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)...